# Why is $S_4/A_4 \cong \Bbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am studying Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra text and I am struggling with the following:

Why is $S_4/A_4 \cong \Bbb{Z}_2$?

Also, why is $S_4/A_4$ abelian?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $A_4$ is a subgroup that has order 12. It's also normal since it's index is 2. So the quotient group is well defined and it has cardinality 2. There is only one group of order 2, up to isomorphism, which is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ . $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is abelian (it is even cyclic). So, $S_4/A_4 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. Since it is isomorphic to an Abelian group, it must also be abelian.